# Pandas cummulative sum based on True/False condition

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using python and need to solve the dataframe as cumsum() the value until the boolean column change its value from True to False. How to solve this task?

```
    Bool       Value      Expected_cumsum
0   False        1                1
1   False        2                3
2   False        4                7
3   True         1                8       
4   False        3                3  << reset from here
5   False        5                8
6   True         2                10
....
```

Thank all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
a = df.Bool.eq(True).cumsum().shift().fillna(0)
df['Expected_cumsum']= df.groupby(a)['Value'].cumsum()
df
```

**Output**

```
    Bool    Value   Expected_cumsum
0   False   1        1
1   False   2        3
2   False   4        7
3   True    1        8
4   False   3        3
5   False   5        8
6   True    2        10
```